# How do I connect my android phone with aurduino mega adk via bluetooth

Tags: android, arduino

I have tried several tutorials but none of them could help me out about this.
I am trying to turn on a led with my android device.
please need help in this case very badly

Comment: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=71296.0

Comment: this is making me more confused :'(
can you help me with any specific tutorial?

Comment: this is the best one i ever tried, please go through this and find all the possible mistakes in your app

Comment: can you help me with source code of both Android and Arduino? 
please help me!!!

Comment: http://softwareways.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-to-arduino-bluetooth-connection.html

Comment: i did exactly the link described 
Still not working